# Altering Revision History with SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, history, revision

Some files in my source repository at work were moved around. Rather than performing a "svn mv $file" operation, the files were moved using "svn rm $old_location/$file" and "SVN add $new_location/$file".

Most of the files are named the same, but are now in different directories. Is there a way to add back the revision history using SVN? I have a map of the old file locations to the new file locations, so it would be nice if I could write a script to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use svnadmin to dump your repository until the revision, in this example 3500, before these unwanted moves took place. Delete the repository and reload the dump file.

```
svnadmin dump RepositoryURL -r0:3500 > svn.dump
rm URL
svnadmin load RepositoryURL < svn.dump
```

Comment: Could the URL just be for individual files?

Comment: @James Thompson: Unfortunately not. It must be a repository URL.

Comment: Perhaps more should be dumped, and just the revisions that went wrong filtered out. This to avoid changes that were made after the moves getting lost.

Answer (score 1):

could also do the above with dumpfilter option.